# How to block URLs that does not contain a specific word using HA proxy

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to block URL's that does not contain a word "Developer" in the URL's query string `urls.primaryName`'s value.

URL's to block:

1. /swaggerui/PetStore/index.html?urls.primaryName=V1-Private
2. /swaggerui/PetStore/index.html?urls.primaryName=V1-Internal

URL's to allow:

1. /swaggerui/PetStore/index.html?urls.primaryName=V1-Developer

Below is the configuration I have tried.

```
frontend http-in
    acl url_petstore_v2 path_beg -i /swaggerui/PetStore/

    use_backend petstore_v2 if url_petstore_v2


backend petstore_v2
    http-request deny if { path_reg /swaggerui/PetStore/index\.html\?urls\.primaryName=(?i)(?!.*Developer).* }

    server petstore1 $PS_HOST$SERVER_ADDRESS_TAIL:$PS_PORT check $TLS_APPEND $HAPROXY_RESOLVER_EXPR
```

Regex expression I have used does match the URL's as you can see in this online regex test tool.

https://regex101.com/r/bXKXez/1

But this configuration is not blocking the URLs and allowing all the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Haproxy has function for query string's parameter's value, `url_param` and its derivatives. In this case `urlp_sub` (substring match) looks promising:

```
http-request deny unless { urlp_sub(urls.primaryName) Developer }
```

From haproxy-2.5 manual:

```
urlp([<name>[,<delim>]]) : string
url_param([<name>[,<delim>]]) : string
This extracts the first occurrence of the parameter <name> in the query
string, which begins after either '?' or <delim>, and which ends before '&',
';' or <delim>. The parameter name is case-sensitive. If no name is given,
any parameter will match, and the first one will be returned. The result is
a string corresponding to the value of the parameter <name> as presented in
the request (no URL decoding is performed). This can be used for session
stickiness based on a client ID, to extract an application cookie passed as a
URL parameter, or in ACLs to apply some checks. Note that the ACL version of
this fetch iterates over multiple parameters and will iteratively report all
parameters values if no name is given

ACL derivatives :
  urlp(<name>[,<delim>])     : exact string match
  urlp_beg(<name>[,<delim>]) : prefix match
  urlp_dir(<name>[,<delim>]) : subdir match
  urlp_dom(<name>[,<delim>]) : domain match
  urlp_end(<name>[,<delim>]) : suffix match
  urlp_len(<name>[,<delim>]) : length match
  urlp_reg(<name>[,<delim>]) : regex match
  urlp_sub(<name>[,<delim>]) : substring match
```